# How to enable `import styles from './local.css' ` syntax in a create-react-app project?

Tags: sass, create-react-app

I used `npx create-react-app myapp --typescript` to create a skeleton project.

My perfer css import styles is `import styles from './App.css` such that I can do something like this

```
<div className={styles.container}>Hello</div>
```

However if i tried this style I will get an error

```
Type error: Cannot find module './App.css'.  TS2307

    2 | import logo from './logo.svg';
    3 |
  > 4 | import styles from './App.css';
```

How can configure my react-app to accept this coding style?

`create-react-app` version is 2.1.3

Answer (score 1):

1. change 'App.css' to 'App.module.css'
2. import it
   `import styles from './App.module.css'`
3. use the classes like this

`<div className={styles.app}>Hello World!</div>`

Reference [Link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import stylesheets the way you did as it is not a js module. You can do this:

`import './App.css'`

You will only be able to do the way you did it if you created styles as js objects and only apply to style attribute not className. Example:

On *Style.js* not css

```
const styles =  {
    container: {
        background: red,
        fontSize: '15px'
    }
}

export default styles;
```

On *App.js*

```
import styles from './styles'
```

and on your render()

```
<div style={styles.container}>Your Content</div>
```

Note its style not class

If you are using typed-css-modules, you will have to run `tcm --watch` alongside or `tcm` by itself. Once you do it, tslint won't give you any errors unless it cannot find the styles.

Comment: The syntax is acceptable if for example https://github.com/Quramy/typed-css-modules However I don't know how to enable it in a `create-react-app` project. Hence my question

Comment: May be you need to do this then. `import * as styles from './styles.css'` and `<div class="${styles.myClass}"></div>` and tsc will take care of it